# How to fix openssl error in Mac Python app?

Tags: python, macos, cx-freeze

I'm building an app using Python. I used `CX_Freeze` to package it for Mac.
However when I install on latest Mac High Sierra version it gives this error:

> errorrequests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.keygen.sh', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/accounts/xxxxx/licenses/actions/validate-key (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",))